# How to assign javascript variable value to HTML Attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having 2 text box.. Value of first text box should been an length of second text box.. Eg: If user gives First text box value as "10", then my second text box should not allow user to type more than 10 characters..

Here is my code..

```js
function field_length() {
  var fieldValue = document.getElementById('Length').value;
  alert(fieldValue);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="Length[]" maxlength="2" class="required" id="Length" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" placeholder="Field length" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="Label[]" class="required" id="Label" maxlength="" onClick="field_length();" placeholder="Field Label" class="form-control">
```

In this code what i did was.. if user is gives value for first field as "5", on tap of second field it will alert the value.. But i want that value to be assigned to Maxlenght attribute. Give me some idea..

Comment: try this **document.getElementById("yourID").maxLength**  .. **L** should be capital. And please do some research before asking such **easy** questions as there are already so many posts available if you **google** it .. thanks

Comment: change `.value` to `.maxlength`

Comment: you should use jquery `$('#Length').attr('maxlength','5')`

Comment: @MayankVadiya he wants to achieve this using javascript as per what his code suggests ..

Comment: @MayankVadiya How's jquery performance?

Comment: Its very faster and very easy to use @HermLuna

Comment: @MayankVadiya did you even try to compare the performance of jquery and nativeJS?

Comment: @HermLuna can please explain what you want to say here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get length and set maxLength attribute.

```
function field_length(){
   var length = $("#Length").val();
  $("#Label").attr("maxlength", length)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use setAttribute
<script type="text/javascript">
     function field_length()
    {
     var fieldValue= document.getElementById('Length').value;
    document.getElementById("Label").setAttribute('maxlength',fieldValue);
     }
    </script>


<input type="text" name="Length[]" maxlength="2"  class="required" id="Length" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" placeholder="Field length"  class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="Label[]" class="required" id="Label" maxlength="" onClick="field_length();" placeholder="Field Label" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#Label").attr("maxlength", length);
```

or

```
$("#Label").prop("maxlength", length);
```

NOTE:

**As of jQuery 1.6. , the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.**